# Foreach loop inside an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have created 2  array, I'm trying to show my first array to another array. So I used foreach statement so I can show each value in my 2nd array like this

```
<?php 
    $first = array('12:00 AM', '1:00 AM', '2:00 AM', '3:00 AM', '4:00 AM', '5:00 AM', '6:00 AM', '7:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM');

    $2nd = array('body' =>array(),);

    foreach($first as $value){
         $2nd['body'] = $value;
    }

   echo json_encode($2nd); ?>
```

The problem is only the 11:AM is showing. So what is my problem in my code guys I really need your help. I'm willing to listen. Thanks

Comment: you can not use `$2nd` you cant start your variable name using number

Comment: You are tracing through the complete $first array but you are not preserving them. So the most recent value is being stored to your second array.For that you have to push the values to the second array. Again the variable name can't start with number

Comment: Thanks for the info ^_^

Answer (score 2):

First: you can't start a variable name with a number ([PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)), and second you need to append ( `added []` ) the value to the array, otherwise you will only get the last value.

```
$first = array( '12:00 AM', '1:00 AM', '2:00 AM', '3:00 AM', '4:00 AM', '5:00 AM', '6:00 AM', '7:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM' );

$second= array( 'body' => array(), );

foreach ( $first as $value ) {
    $second['body'][] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($second);
```

You could also use a shorter way:

```
$first = array( '12:00 AM', '1:00 AM', '2:00 AM', '3:00 AM', '4:00 AM', '5:00 AM', '6:00 AM', '7:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM' );

$second = array( 'body' =>  $first );

echo json_encode( $second );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `=` php equal operator

```
$first = array( '12:00 AM', '1:00 AM', '2:00 AM', '3:00 AM', '4:00 AM', '5:00 AM', '6:00 AM', '7:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM' );

$second['body'] = $first;

print json_encode($second);
```

**Tip:** variable names cannot start with a digit, so rename the `$2nd` to `$second` http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Here working sample https://eval.in/443545

Answer (score 0):

Change variable name. (i.e) cannot begin with `digit`.
Consider using it as `$second`

```
$first = array( '12:00 AM', '1:00 AM', '2:00 AM', '3:00 AM', '4:00 AM', '5:00 AM', '6:00 AM', '7:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM' );   

$second= array( 'body' => array(), );
foreach ( $first as $value ) 
    {
     $second['body'][] = $value;
    }
 echo json_encode($second);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't append your values from `$first` to `$second['body']` but overwrite them.
Either use the `array_push` function or `$second['body'][] = $value;`
Edit: And yes, of course, respect the variable naming rules as already said in the other answers.